# Convert Attributes to same level as parent with data xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to move my child nodes attributes as element to parent. for ex. Change the below xml

```
<Parent>
 <Children>
 <Child-id Name="John Doe">52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53df7</Child>
 <Child-id Name="Some One">52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53daa</Child>

 </Children>
</Parent>
```

to

```
<Parent>

 <child-id>52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53df7</child>
 <Name>John Doe</Name>
 <child-id>52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53daa</child>
 <Name>John Doe</Name>
</Parent>
```

Comment: Right, and how's that going?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the XSLT below. For creating elements from the attribute names, attribute value templates have to be used

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Child-id">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:variable name="attrName" select="local-name()" />
            <xsl:element name="{$attrName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />    
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<Parent>
   <Children>
      <Child-id>52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53df7</Child-id>
      <Name>John Doe</Name>
      <Child-id>52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53daa</Child-id>
      <Name>Some One</Name>
   </Children>
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT-1.0 file transforms you XML to the desired state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">       <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="Children">          <!-- Remove 'Children' element -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="Child-id">          <!-- Transform 'Child-id' element -->
    <child-id><xsl:value-of select="." /></child-id>
    <Name><xsl:value-of select="@Name" /></Name>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<Parent>
    <child-id>52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53df7</child-id>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <child-id>52bf9104-2c5e-4f1f-a66d-552ebcc53daa</child-id>
    <Name>Some One</Name>
</Parent>
```